# Node spacing when drawing line between them

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I want to draw line between specified nodes with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node [name=A, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (-1,1) {};
    \node [name=B, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (1,1) {};
    \node [name=C, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (1,-1) {};
    \node [name=D, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (-1,-1) {};

    \draw [thick] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [thick] (B) -- (C);
    \draw [thick] (C) -- (D);
    \draw [thick] (D) -- (A);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But even though I've set `inner sep` and `outer sep` to `0pt`, there are still gaps at the corners. What do I have to do, so that there are no more gaps at the corners and it looks like a clean rectangle with one continuous line?

This is how the compiled image from the code above looks like:

[image: corner gaps]

Comment: In this case you could do `\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=-2*\pgflinewidth,shorten <=-2*\pgflinewidth]...` but the cleaner way is to draw one path instead of four.

Comment: Cleaner: `\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [name=A, coordinate] at (-1,1) {};
    \node [name=B, coordinate] at (1,1) {};
    \node [name=C, coordinate] at (1,-1) {};
    \node [name=D, coordinate] at (-1,-1) {};

    \draw [thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) --cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first assume you want to keep the nodes as nodes, not coordinates, and want to construct the rectangle in four separate paths. Then you could add `linecap=rect` and use the `center` anchors.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=rect]

    \node [name=A, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (-1,1) {};
    \node [name=B, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (1,1) {};
    \node [name=C, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (1,-1) {};
    \node [name=D, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (-1,-1) {};

    \draw [thick] (A.center) -- (B.center);
    \draw [thick] (B.center) -- (C.center);
    \draw [thick] (C.center) -- (D.center);
    \draw [thick] (D.center) -- (A.center);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This works, but arguably only by accident because this is a rectangle. On the other hand, if you use `coordinate` "shapes" and draw the thing in one stretch, this will also work for lines that meet at angles different from 90 or 180 degrees.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [name=A, coordinate] at (-1,1) {};
    \node [name=B, coordinate] at (1,1) {};
    \node [name=C, coordinate] at (1,-1) {};
    \node [name=D, coordinate] at (-1,-1) {};

    \draw [thick] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) --cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result of these codes is rather unspectacular.

[image]